# gpt3 fine tuning with openai not learning

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, openai-api, gpt-3

For my fine tuning jsonl files, I wanted a model that could predict the gender of the speaker given a statement. For instance, the prompt: "i went to buy a skirt today" has completion as "female".

I created several examples and gave it to gpt3 to finetune. I then fed the sentence "i went to pick my wife up from the shops" to the resulting model. I expected to get a gender as response but I got a whole story about picking up my wife from the shops.

It's as if gpt-3 didn't learn anything from my fine tuning at all.

I have a few questions:

1. Is fine tuning equivalent to writing a few examples in openai playground and getting gpt-3 to guess what comes next?
2. After fine tuning, do you only pay for the tokens in the prompt/completion of subsequent runs? So If I spend $100 training a model on a million examples, I will then only have to pay for the individual prompt/completion of subsequent calls?
3. The chat bot for instance, come with a context sentence before the back and forth exchange of 2 chat participants. Something like "this is a conversation between a rude man named John and a young girl named Sarah". How can i incorporate such context into fine tuning structure of {"prompt":"...","completion":..."}?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open AI Fine Tuning is a process of using a pre-trained model on a new dataset to improve the performance of the model on the new dataset. It is really important to have a specific prompt you are working with so the fine-tuning model knows exactly what you are training for.
2. Exactly, the benefit of fine tuning is that you won't have to pay for prompting the standard model with information each time. And, it improved performance for your specific usecase of course.
3. For that example, you would train it in an entire long conversation between rude john and a young girl named sarah. But, keep in mind which 'person' you are wanting the ai to be.

Rude John 'AI': Lorem Ipsum
Sarah: Lorem Ipsum
*Train long conversation*

But you would also want to train Rude John 'AI' to talking to others as well.

Comment: das 1. mean that you cant really "teach" new knowledge? just kind of improve the clarity and quality of answers to knowledge thats already there ?